# Sudden connection problems

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

The Azure IOT Hub is suddenly experiencing connectivity issues, since May 20.

We have two Multitech Coundit gateways that have run impeccably for approx. 1 year, but suddenly can no longer connect to Azure IOT Hub.
The SSL certificates are still valid.

I've tried to generate new keys for that one gateway, but it didn't work either.

Since the two gateways are quite limited in terms of hardware, we cannot use the dedicated node-red Aure connectors, but have to use a standard MQTT connection.

The Azure log provides the following output:

```
ResourceType: IOTHUBS
OperationName: deviceConnect
ResultType: 401003
ResultDescription: IotHubUnauthorized
Level: Error
SourceSystem: Azure
authType: null
protocol: Mqtt
statusCode: 401
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but the hub will reject messages if the device time is over 2 seconds out of sync (Unfortunately I cannot find reference for this now).

Example issue [Connection Not Accepted: 0x5: Not Authorized](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1141)